# AlertDialog.Builder cannot be resolved to a type error

Tags: android, android-dialog

I receive the error on the line below:

```
AlertDialog.Builder  alrtDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

The Error show is :

> AlertDialog.Builder cannot be resolved to a type

I import the following for this:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
```

the java code in the example(from android programming unleashed) includes
android.app.AlertDialog but importing this results in message: conflicts with a type defined in the same file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to import this

`import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder`

Comment: Grats on beating the other answers by mere minutes. In any case, what would you do if this didn't resolve the issue? I'm still getting a "can not resolve symbol" in an Android LibGDX project.

Answer (score 6):

Try to `import`

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

and also if your using this line `AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();` remove it and try.

Answer (score 3):

first check that you have import the corresponding package

`import android.app.AlertDialog;` and then c

check that you are using your activity instance

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivityname.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must import your ***AlertDialog***

```
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder
```

instead of

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
```

Also Change

```
AlertDialog.Builder  alrtDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
```